# Identity Server 4 and relative URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, authorization, identityserver4

I have an application that includes a reactjs UI, .net core Web API and Identity Server 4 for authorization. The application works fine in my development environment.
Now, I am deploying it to staging(IIS) and I can only use a relative URL for my Identity server and my URLs are as below:

```
https://www.something/ui
https://www.something/api
https://www.something/identityserver
```

when I try to see a page, UI redirect me successfully to the Identity Server login page. I can login as well but then it redirects to a URL like:

```
https://www.something/signin-oidc?code=ED2XXXXXXXX....
```

and see Server Error Page with this message: **[404 - File or directory not found.
The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.]**

When I check my network I can see that Web API authorization is unsuccessful too.
I guess the issue is related to identity server relative URL but I have no idea how I should fix it.

Comment: can you post your Startup. cs file?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the **/signin-oidc** By setting the **CallBackPAth** on the **OpenIdConnectOptions** object (AddOpenIDConnect(...))

See the source for OpenIdConnectOptions [here](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect/OpenIdConnectOptions.cs,5cc7fe6410c2ed93)